# Understand the conditional probability

Tags: probability

The formula of the conditional probability is $$P(B\,\vert\,A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(A\,\vert\,B)P(B)}{P(A)}$$

I think ask an example would easier to understand. Suppose we have an urn that contain $6$ tiles. We first draw two tiles from the urn and then draw one more from the remaining $4$. Now suppose that we know the last drawn is $6$, find the probability that we have a $4$ as the lager number of the first draw.

If I apply the formula, I would have 
$$P(M=4\,\vert\,N=6)=\frac{P(N=6\,\vert\,M=4)P(M=4)}{P(N=6)}$$ I know $P(M=4)=3/15$. How to compute the other two probabilities? How do I count them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find $P(N=6\mid M=4)$, note that *given* that $M=4$, you know that whatever tiles remain must include $6$, since you drew a $4$ and something less than a $4$. There are $4$ tiles left and one is a six, so $P(N = 6\mid M=4)=...?$

To find $P(N=6)$, you just need to count the total number of ways to draw $3$ tiles (in order) and the number of ways to draw $3$ tiles (in order) such that the last one is a $6$.

Alternatively, instead of computing $P(N=6\mid M=4)P(M=4)$ in the numerator, you could compute $P(N=6 \cap M=4)$. This just requires counting the total number of ways to choose $3$ cards (in order) and the number of ways to draw $3$ tiles (in order) such that the first two are a $4$ and something less than a $4$ (not necessarily in that order) and the last is a $6$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability for selecting number four and 1 from 3 numbers when selecting 2 from 6 numbers is: $$\mathsf P(M=4) = {\binom{3}{1}}/{\binom{6}{2}} = 1/5$$

The probability that the third number selected will be six when it is selected from any 6 numbers is: $$\mathsf P(N=6) = 1/6$$

The probability for selecting six as the third number when selecting from the 4 numbers that are neither four nor 1 from 3 numbers-less-than-four, is: $$\mathsf P(N=6\mid M=4)= 1/4$$

The probability for selecting number four and 1 from 3 numbers, when selecting 2 from 5 numbers-that-are-not-six, is: $$\mathsf P(M=4\mid N=6)= \binom 3 1/\binom 5 2 = 3/10$$

And there we go :

$$\dfrac 3{10} ~=~ \mathsf P(M=4\mid N=6)~=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(N=6\mid M=4)~\mathsf P(M=4)}{\mathsf P(N=6)} ~=~\dfrac{\tfrac 14\cdot\tfrac 15}{\tfrac 1 6}~=~\dfrac 3{10}$$

---

Just to round off: The probability of selecting four and 1 from 3 numbers in the first 2 places *then* selecting six in the 3rd place, when selecting 3 from 6 numbers in the first 3 places, is: $$\mathsf P(M=4, N=6)~=~\dfrac{\binom 3 1 2!\cdot 1}{\binom 6 3 3!}~=~\dfrac 1{20}$$